# While loading yaml file in python code, is there a way to avoid duplicate keys?

Tags: python, yaml

Is there a way to raise exception when step is given twice under build1 (look at file.yaml content).

I am using f = yaml.load(open(file.yaml, 'r'))

```
file.yaml content - 
build1:
  step: 'step1'
  time: '20s'
  step: 'step2'

build2:
  step: 'step1'
```